# I am wondering how to use screen -S in Crontab

Tags: cron

When my computer is rebooted, I want to run 'screen -S 1', using Crontab, and run Minecraft on Screen.

What should I do?

Minecraft execution command
I'm using **@reboot sh /home/root/start.bat**

Comment: Don't. You put a SCRIPT in crontab as you did and add the screen command to that script. You can use screen as you would type in in command line with absolute path. But I really would suggest to use the systemd service provided.

Comment: Try full path and, maybe `/bin/bash`. `@reboot /bin/sh /home/root/start.bat`

Comment: Is start.bat a valid sh script?  File extension .bat is usually associated with DOS/Windows batch files, not {Li,U}nix sh shell scripts.  Try running 'sh /home/root/start.bat' to see if it is even going to work outside of cron.